# How to use percentile_disc on array

Tags: google-bigquery

I am able to use `approx_quantiles` on an array by doing

```sql
(select approx_quantiles(reps, 10)[offset(5)] from unnest(arr_tab.arr) as reps) as med,
```

where `arr_tab.arr` is an array of values.

I would like to get exact numbers the same way with `percentile_disc` (the arrays are relatively small), but the following:

```sql
(select percentile_disc(reps, .5) from unnest(arr_tab.arr) as reps) as med,
```

gives the error

> Analytic function PERCENTILE_DISC cannot be called without an OVER clause at [17:11] Learn More about BigQuery SQL Functions.

Here is a full example query, which runs if I comment out the `percentile_disc` attempt:

```sql
with arr_tab as (
SELECT [1, 2, 3] AS arr, 'a' as label UNION ALL
    SELECT [4, 5, 6], 'c' UNION ALL
    SELECT [10, 11, 12], 'd'
)

, q2 as (
select
  label,
  (select approx_quantiles(reps, 10)[offset(5)] from unnest(arr_tab.arr) as reps) as med,
  -- (select percentile_disc(reps, .5) from unnest(arr_tab.arr) as reps) as med2,
from arr_tab
)

select *
from q2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below

```
(SELECT PERCENTILE_DISC(reps, .5) OVER() FROM UNNEST(arr_tab.arr) AS reps LIMIT 1) AS med2
```